# Can I log in to Debian XFCE without a password?

Tags: linux, xfce, debian-jessie

Some Linux distros like Sabayon and Ubuntu allow users to log in without a password, but can I do that on Debian? If I can, how could I?

Comment: Why would you want to allow such a huge security hole?

Comment: The account wouldn't have sudo privileges, and it's specifically for other people to use

Comment: Lots of useful context in [this Ask Ubuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/530072/how-to-auto-login-in-xubuntu-or-ubuntu-server-with-xfce), much or most of which should still apply to Debian.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your display manager.
If you use lightdm, and i think its the default for xfce on debian. you can edit the file 
`/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`, uncomment the line `#autologin-user=` and change it to `autologin-user=YOURUSERNAME`

Comment: Note that this has to be in the [?SeatDefaults] section, not the [LightDM] section
Source: https://wiki.debian.org/LightDM#Enable_autologin